# Django: Make log-in time invariable to avoid user enumeration attack

Tags: python, django, security

Currently I'm having an issue where anyone can check if a user exists or not, simply by trying to log-in with the username and timing how long it takes to error out (non-existent usernames take a shorter time to reject, regardless of the password).

I use Django's `AuthenticationForm` to authenticate the user, and then do a bit of other stuff. Is there an easy Django/Python method of changing this behavior? Or is this more a design pattern kind of problem?

Comment: This was reported as a Django bug (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20760) and fixed.  Is it the 'other stuff' that generates the timing difference or are you on an old version of Django?